# libcurl link with mingw and clion

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to build my project using curl, but I have this result :
    undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'

This is my CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(score)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(score ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_library(libcurl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libcurl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "c:/MinGW/lib")

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lcurl")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}    ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

Moreover, I put my file libcurl.a, etc... in the correct directory "c:/MinGW/lib".

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to compile the source files that call the curl functions with the `CURL_STATICLIB` macro defined.

Do you have access to the curl-config utility? It's there when you build curl from source.  Run it with the `--cflags` option to get the compiler flags required and the `--libs` option to get linker requirements.

For example, in my mingw environment, the cflags reported are `-DCURL_STATICLIB -I/mingw/local/include` and the lib flags reported are `-L/mingw/local/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lz -lws2_32`.